# Windows Phone Store - its possible to disable application switcher screen screenshot

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have disabled the functionality to take a screenshot from my app using:

`ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().IsScreenCaptureEnabled = false;`

But I would like to hide all the content before the application is suspended/sent to background so the thumbnail appearing in the recent apps or application switcher screen does not show any confidential information.

Have tried to hide content on the onSuspend and Visibility_Changed events, but i think the sceenshot is taken just the moment the user press the Home Button (the one with the Windows logo).

Do you know any way of disabling that feature?

Comment: I think you can handle back pressed, though I don't know if that will trigger on back held.

Comment: HardWareButtons class does not has the HOME button on its enumeration. I already handle BACK button so when im in the starting page the application will shutdown (no shown in recent app list)

Answer (score 1):

Subscribing to the WindowActivated event might be worth a try. The name is misleading as it will be launched on (any kind of) deactivation as well; which is what you want. I use it to save information on exit scenarios such as Home Button press but have not tested whether you could do a quick redraw or not.

```
Protected Overrides Async Sub OnLaunched(e As LaunchActivatedEventArgs)
    ''Stuff
    AddHandler Window.Current.Activated, AddressOf WindowActivated
    ''Stuff
End Sub

Private Sub WindowActivated(sender As Object, e As Windows.UI.Core.WindowActivatedEventArgs)
    If e.WindowActivationState = Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindowActivationState.Deactivated Then
        ''Hide your confidential visuals here
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Pity its not fast enough to redraw the UI before system takes the screenshot. But pretty useful since i was playing with the Visibility_Changed event to identify when the application was being suspended (saw many examples doing that). So BIG THUMBS UP for your contribution